# Crystal Reports tools are not active in VS toolbox

Tags: .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, reporting

I have installed SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2022 after I had already started on my project. But when I try to use these tools from Toolbox, they seem to be disabled!

[image]

I started a new project, Windows Forms (.NET framework), and I found that they work properly.
My project (the first one, that I'm actually working on), is Windows Forms only with .NET 7.0.

I can add a Crystal report, but not the crystal report viewer and other tools.